# How to use timestamp as 'x' value for data visualization?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, time-series, data-visualization

Please see the screenshot of the dataframe I am using:

**[image: Screenshot of dataframe]**

I am trying to use the index value ('TIMESTAMP') as 'x' to do data visualization, however it gives me value error.

Here's the error I am seeing:

**[image: Screenshot of Value Error]**

Here's the code I used:

```
sns.scatterplot(data=crimes_2018, x='TIMESTAMP', y='TYPE')
```

If I want to use the index 'TIMESTAMP' as 'x' value. Do I need to enter additional information than its index name?

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the exception stack trace you are seeing?

Comment: Hi @AK47! I added a screenshot of Value Error I am seeing, and here's the link to the screenshot for your quick reference! **[link to the screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/lDOK0y7.jpg)** Thank you so much for looking into this for me!

Answer (score 0):

We can map the `TYPE` column which is categorical to numerical, and then call `sns.scatterlot`

- Step 1 - Reproducing the Data

```
>>> import seaborn as sns
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import random

>>> dates = pd.date_range('2018-01-01','2018-01-10')

>>> reas = ['Mischief', 'Theft of Bicycle', 'Theft from Vehicle', 'Break and Enter']
>>> reasons = [random.choice(reas) for i in range(10)]

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'TIMESTAMP':dates,'TYPE':reasons})
>>> df
   TIMESTAMP              TYPE
0 2018-01-01   Break and Enter
1 2018-01-02   Break and Enter
2 2018-01-03          Mischief
3 2018-01-04   Break and Enter
4 2018-01-05  Theft of Bicycle
5 2018-01-06          Mischief
6 2018-01-07   Break and Enter
7 2018-01-08   Break and Enter
8 2018-01-09          Mischief
9 2018-01-10  Theft of Bicycle
```

- Step 2 - Creating mapped column

```
>>> dct = {item:i for i, item in enumerate(reas)}
>>> df['TYPE_MAPPED'] = df['TYPE'].map(dct)
   TIMESTAMP              TYPE  TYPE_MAPPED
0 2018-01-01   Break and Enter            3
1 2018-01-02   Break and Enter            3
2 2018-01-03          Mischief            0
3 2018-01-04   Break and Enter            3
4 2018-01-05  Theft of Bicycle            1
5 2018-01-06          Mischief            0
6 2018-01-07   Break and Enter            3
7 2018-01-08   Break and Enter            3
8 2018-01-09          Mischief            0
9 2018-01-10  Theft of Bicycle            1

>>> df[['TIMESTAMP','TYPE_MAPPED']].set_index('TIMESTAMP').plot()
```

[image: Scatterplot]